# Monit "can't find filesystem"

Tags: monit

I'm finding monit unable to monitor a filesystem effectively. I've added a file `/etc/monit.d/disk.cnf` with the following:

```
check device disk1 with path /dev/root
  if space usage > 85% then exec "/bin/custom-alert"
```

...And when I `monit reload`, the monit log tells me:

```
[PST Jan  4 14:48:39] error    : 'disk1' filesystem doesn't exist
[PST Jan  4 14:48:39] info     : 'disk1' trying to restart
```

Okay, so I `cat /proc/cmdline` and learn that `root=/dev/sda`, and then I replace `/dev/root` with `/dev/sda` in my `disk.cnf` file. Then the monit log tells me:

```
[PST Jan  4 14:46:35] error    : Device /dev/sda not found in /etc/mtab
[PST Jan  4 14:46:35] error    : 'disk1' unable to read filesystem /dev/sda state
```

Indeed, `/etc/mtab` references `/dev/root` instead of `/dev/sda`.

**Why can't monit access the filesystem when I specify `/dev/root` or `/dev/sda` on this machine?**

---

More info: `df -h` outputs the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       173G  146G   26G  85% /
devtmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            32G  3.2G   29G  11% /run
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Show the output of `df -h` or `mount`.

Comment: @ewwhite updated OP with the output of `df -h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monit requires the actual mountpoint to be specified.

If you're trying to get the root filesystem, you should use `/`.

```
check device root with path /
    if SPACE usage > 85% then alert
```

Comment: Thanks! +1. But I'm running the same version of Monit (2.26) on another server, and I specify the device `/dev/sda` instead of the mount point `/` on it, and it tests successfully. And the doc also says that the device is acceptable. Do you have any idea why the device isn't working on the server at hand?

Comment: Use the path specification of `/`. Why wouldn't you use that?

Comment: Thanks, @ewwite. I am using it. I just asked hoping to learn the explanation for why specifying the device doesn't work when the mount shows a device of `/dev/root`.